# Why do we blow when we're out of breath?

Tags: breathing, lungs

When people are out of breath from exercising, instead of breathing normally they partially obstruct their expirations by blowing out instead of breathing out.

Why is this?

EDIT: [This photo](http://www.mylifefitness.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/fatman_running-624x416.jpg) illustrates what I'm referring to.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You have to breathe out in order to breathe in again…

Comment: I don't. I start panting. This is opinion based I guess.

Comment: @canadianer: You don't understand the difference between blowing and breathing out normally?

Comment: Why did 'AliceD' mark this question as 'unclear what [I'm] asking', when her comment shows that she understood the question perfectly? I give up. No one is capable of answering, or, it seems, even understanding my simple question.

Comment: @EmmaV, after a while, thinking about it, I now understand what you are asking. Alice is clearly saying that the answer(s) would be opinion based and thus not constructive and hence put a block on any further answers. In my opinion based answer, I would say I do that so the strong air flow does not go through my teeth because it gives me a strange feeling when it goes through my teeth... Like others, I think the question could have been better expressed.

Comment: @EmmaV Do you mean why do we typically exhale harder than inhale after strenuous exercise?

Comment: What is the difference between blowing out and breathing out?

Answer (score 2):

**Trying to rephrase the question**

If I understand the question (and what you missunderstand) correctly, I think one could rephrase the post as

*When one spends some time under water and come back to the surface, one usually breath out and then breath in. This is surprising to me because I would expect the person to be out of air and therefore wouldn't need to breath out before breathing in.*

Let me know if I failed to understand your question and misunderstandings

**Answer**

We don't incorporate the air we breath in our lungs. We only use the molecules of oxygen $O_2$ from the air (which takes ~20% of the total volume). This molecule goes in the blood, reach the cells and react with sugar to produce energy. The waster of this reaction is another molecule $CO_2$ that needs to be exhaled through the lungs.

So, really the volume and of air that we have in our lungs doesn't vary much (It actually increase a little bit as we had some carbons). Only the composition of the air that we have in our lungs changes. After some time, we need to renew this air and for this purpose we first need to breath out the air that is contain a high density of $CO_2$ before breathing in.

This is why when sticking the head out of the water many people first breath out and then breath in. Note, however that one can breath out all its air underwater and then only has to breath in when back at the surface.

**EDIT**

Are you asking why do we contract our lips during sport?

If yes, I think it very much depend from one person to another. There is probably no physiological advantage/disadvantage at doing so and it probably is just a consequence of expressing pain on our face.

Comment: That's not what I mean. When people are out of breath, they breath more heavily than normal, but instead of expiring gently as normal, they 'blow'. By this I mean they partially close their mouth so that there's a small opening and blow through it, often making thier cheeks bulge. Inspirations are still normal, albeit deeper. Here's an image I found quickly: http://watchfit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/xshortness-of-breath-during-exercise_1-1024x682.jpeg.pagespeed.ic.qrPeKJuXUm.jpg

Comment: Your comment seems very unrelated to your post...but ok. I tried to answer to what might be your question (still unclear to me) in an edit in my answer above.

Comment: My comment is an elaboration on my question. I'm not asking why we contract our lips during sport. I personally 'blow' when out of breath because a rapid expiration when out of breath is uncomfortable. This is doubtless why others do it too. I thought that there must be a physiological explanation for it.

Comment: Well you blow to make room to breath in again, isn't it? Or you just stop inhaling altogether?!

Comment: I find it hard to believe that someone with a PhD genuinely can't understand my question, and is confusing blowing with normal expiration. Does one 'breathe' up a balloon? I make a point of always phrasing my questions as simply as possible in order to accommodate non-native English speakers, and I'm really at a loss as to how this question could possibly be any simpler to understand.

Comment: To clarify: I'm **not** saying people stop expiring when they're out of breath. Why would I say that? It's idiotic. I'm saying that when people are out of breath, they expire by **blowing** instead of expiring by breathing out normally, as a person at rest does.

Comment: Note also btw that I don't have a PhD (yet) as I am currently a PhD student. I'll delete my answer once I'll understand your question (and will then try to suggest an edit to your post).

Comment: I am not sure what is this difference between blowing and breathing out. Is it specific to the lips position or to the amount of air flowing through the mouth (or something else)?

Comment: It puzzling that my last comment has enabled you to understand my question, since the comment is essentially the same as the question. The difference between blowing and breathing out is obvious. Do both, and you'll notice the difference. Blowing is more forceful than normal breathing, and the mouth is made smaller.

Comment: And so is you question, why do we need to inhale and exhale more air when we are exercising?

Comment: You're not serious, surely. The reason why we breathe more when exercising is taught in Junior school. How is this relevant anyway?

Comment: So what is the point that interest you about blowing if it is not related to the amount of air? Is it the position of the lips?

Comment: I will soon give up trying to understand your question. It is the job of the OP to make its question easy to understand and it appears that we all struggle with yours.

Comment: No offense intended, but you might as well give up now. Stop wasting your time. It's impossible for this question to be any clearer, and yet it is still ostensibly beyond everyone's comprehension. Thanks for your efforts anyway.